# How is the linear SVM's cost function derived from the Lagrangian (for the primal form)?

Tags: svm, mathematical-statistics

This is the cost function that seems to be used for training linear SVM classifiers:

$J(\mathbf{w}, b) = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{w}^T \cdot \mathbf{w} \quad + \quad C {\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}max\left(0, 1 - y_i (\mathbf{w}^T \cdot \mathbf{x}_i + b)\right)}$

I can see why it would work, but I am wondering how it was derived from the linear SVM constrained optimization problem (primal form)?

$\underset{\mathbf{w}, b}{\operatorname{minimize}}\quad{\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^t \cdot \mathbf{w}} \\
\text{subject to} \quad t^{(i)}(\mathbf{w}^t \cdot \mathbf{x}^{(i)} + b) \ge 1 \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, \cdots, m$

I suppose it comes from the generalized Lagrangian?

$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w}, b, \mathbf{\alpha}) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^t \cdot \mathbf{w} - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{\alpha^{(i)} \left(t^{(i)}(\mathbf{w}^t \cdot \mathbf{x}^{(i)} + b) - 1\right)} \\
\text{with}\quad \alpha^{(i)} \ge 0 \quad \text{for }i = 1, 2, \cdots, m$

But I don't see how you go from this equation to the hinge loss function $max(0, 1-t)$.

Any idea?